# How to count the number of membership, output the results in a grouped tables using aliases?

Tags: mysql, sql, db2

I am trying to output the number of members who have a Basic and AAA membership in a format that looks like this

```
#BASIC      #AAA
----------- -----------
     43          18
```

here's my code:

```
select count(club) as #Basic, count(club) as #AAA 
from yrb_member
where club = 'Basic' 
group by club;
```

But I keep getting an output that's like this:

```
#BASIC      #AAA
----------- -----------
     18          18
     43          43
```

How would I go about correcting this?

The database data is all varchars:

```
insert into yrb_member (club, cid) values
('Basic',1),
```

Comment: can you give sample table data you are retrieving?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works in near all RDBMS

```
select 
  sum(CASE WHEN club='Basic' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as #Basic
, sum(CASE WHEN club='AAA' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)   as #AAA 
from yrb_member
where club in ('Basic', 'AAA');
```

if avaiable in RDBMS - this looks better

```
select 
  count(*) FILTER (WHERE club='Basic') as #Basic
, count(*) FILTER (WHERE club='AAA')   as #AAA 
from yrb_member
where club in ('Basic', 'AAA');
```

Comment: perfect the first script works, is there a way to contact you directly? I have a few more related questions.

Comment: Ask questions on stackoverflow - this is fastest way